# attr_accessor returns nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor

I want a temporary attribute which I can use in the controller.
I thought `attr_accessor` is the best way to do this.
But when I submit the `users_binded`-input, the following error occurs:

`Template is missing: Missing template schedule/invite_now, application/invite_now with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * ../views`

I want to find the user with the `users_binded`-input in the database, as you can see in the controller.
**I don't know how to use the temporary-attribute in the controller.**
Should it be `Schedule.users_binded` or `:users_binded` or something else?

**schedule-model:**

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :users_binded
end
```

**schedule-view:**

```
<%= form_for @schedule_invite, :as => :schedule, :url => schedule_invite_path, :method => :post, :html => {:class => 'navbar-form', :role => 'login'} do |schedule_form_builder| %>
  <p>
    <strong>..Benutzer:</strong>
    <%= schedule_form_builder.text_field :users_binded, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Benutzer'%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong><br>
    <%= @schedule_invite.title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Ort:</strong><br>
    <%= @schedule_invite.location %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Datum und Uhrzeit:</strong><br>
    <%= @schedule_invite.date_time.strftime("%A, %d.%m.%Y") %>
    <%= @schedule_invite.date_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>
  </p>
  <p class="pull-right">
    <%= link_to "Zurück", root_path, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>&nbsp;
    <%= schedule_form_builder.submit 'Termin teilen?', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**schedule-controller:**

```
class ScheduleController < ApplicationController
def invite_now
    begin #try
      #user_name = @schedule_invite.users_binded.to_s
      user_binded = User.find_by_name(:user_binded)
    rescue #catch
      if user_binded.nil?
        flash[:notice] = 'Der Benutzer konnte nicht gefunden werden.'
        @schedule_invite = current_user.schedules.find(params[:id])
        render :action => "invite"
      else
        @schedule_invite = user_binded.schedules.find(params[:id])
        user_binded.schedules << @schedule_invite
        flash[:notice] = 'Der Termin wird nun mit dem Benutzer ' + user_binded.name + 'geteilt.'
        redirect_to :root
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**routes:**

```
post "schedule/invite/:id" => "schedule#invite_now"
```

---

**EDIT:**
I changed the controller to this:

```
def invite_now
    begin #try
      #user_name = @schedule_invite.users_binded.to_s
      user_binded = User.find_by_name(params[:user_binded])
    rescue #catch
      if user_binded.nil?
        flash[:notice] = 'Der Benutzer konnte nicht gefunden werden.'
        @schedule_invite = current_user.schedules.find(params[:id])
        render :action => "invite"
      end
    end

    if user_binded.nil?
      flash[:notice] = 'Der Benutzer konnte nicht gefunden werden.'
      @schedule_invite = current_user.schedules.find(params[:id])
      render :action => "invite"
    else
      @schedule_invite = user_binded.schedules.find(params[:id])
      user_binded.schedules << @schedule_invite
      flash[:notice] = 'Der Termin wird nun mit dem Benutzer ' + user_binded.name + 'geteilt.'
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end
```

So that I don't need a `invite_now.html.erb`.
The problem that occurs is the following (maybe there is a attr_accessor-problem):
The SQL-Statement
`user_binded = User.find_by_name(params[:user_binded])`
returns/loads
`User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" IS NULL LIMIT 1`,
so that the attr_accessor isn't correct ?
As **Doon** said: "attr_accsessor would be used on an instance."
Is the solution the following ?

```
@schedule_invite = current_user.schedules.find(params[:id])
@schedule_invite.user_binded = User.find_by_name(params[:users_binded])
```

It only makes sense if the attributes type can be everything (ex. Type of User).
Any Ideas ?

---

**EDIT2:**
I try to check the `params[:users_binded]` with the following:
`flash[:notice] = params[:users_binded]`
and this error occurs:
`can't convert nil into String`, so that the param users_binded wont be set correctly.

**RAJ ...** said I should add the params to the question:

```
private
def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit(:id, :titel, :location, :date_time)
end
```

I think here is the problem..

Comment: You need to have a template called `scheduled/invite_now.html.erb`, that's what the error says.

Comment: This is not what I expected. Did I use the `attr_accessor` correctyl in the controller?

Comment: nothing to do with attr_accessor persea.  Just that your logic doesn't throw an excpetion so it is trying to render the default template.  attr_accsessor would be used on an instance. so you would need to ahve something like `@schedule = Schedule.find(schedule_id)`, and then `@schedule.user_binded`  but what exactly does user_binded do, what is its intention?

Comment: userX wants to invite userY to his schedule. user_binded should be userY. That's my intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is not related to `attr_accessor` at all. That's just fine. Problem is with template rendering.

So, you need to add template view `invite_now.html.erb` in your `views/schedule/` directory

Than in your controller:

you need to use `params[:schedule][:users_binded]` instead of `:user_binded`. So it will be like

```
 user_binded = User.find_by_name(params[:schedule][:users_binded])
```

Comment: If I use `params[:users_binded]` the SQL-statement looks like this: `User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" IS NULL LIMIT 1` IS NULL is not what I typed in.

Comment: @Ismoh post your params coming to the action

Comment: I add them to **EDIT2**. I hope I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Ismoh by params I meant the values coming from the form to controller's action. NOT the `schedule_params`. It will be in the form of hash, you can check it in logs

Comment: Sorry. `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sj0Ra5Y/84oo24tXEkEltoDWht+1GKN/j+A5nHwZu5c=", "schedule"=>{"users_binded"=>"Ismoh2"}, "commit"=>"Termin teilen?", "id"=>"25"}`

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew there was a problem with the attr_accessor. It works fine now.